# CollectionView - collection data not being passed to childView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I'm trying to make the **collectionView** work , but I'm not really sure whether the CollectionView initiates the fetch method automatically and then populates the ChildViews with the fetched data. Or is it something I need to do manually? I have checked the Marionette doc page but I couldn't find any proper example that would answer my question.

The below example is what I've got so far , the collection is filled up with all the required data, but the data aren't passed to childview for some reason.

The below JSON is returned whenever I call 'http://localhost/GetCategories':

**JSON data:**

```
[{"category_id":"Category1","category_name":"Category One"}, 
 {"category_id":"Category2","category_name":"Category Two"}]
```

collection:

```
  define([ 'underscore',  'backbone',  'models/MainMenu/MM.model.category'], function(_, Backbone, m_Category){
      var CategoriesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: m_Category,

        url : 'GetCategories';

        initialize: function() {
            console.log('CategoriesCollection initialized...');
            this.fetch()
        }

      });


  return CategoriesCollection;
});
```

**collectionView:**

```
define([ 'backbone', 'underscore', 'marionette', 
    'collections/MainMenu/collection.categories' , 
    'layouts/MainMenu/itemview.category'], 
    function (Backbone, _, Marionette, c_Categories, iv_Category) {
    "use strict";
    var CategoriesCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

        tagName: 'div',

        template: null,

        id: 'categories',

        childView: iv_Category,

        collection : new c_Categories(),

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('Categories Collection: initialized');

            /// or should I call fetch() from within the CV? 
            /// but how do I then pass all the data to ChildView? 
            this.collection.fetch().done(function(){

            })
        },
        onRender: function(){
            console.log(this.collection) ///<-- shows all the JSON data properly
        },
        onShow: function(){
        }
    });

    return CategoriesCollectionView;
});
```

**ItemView:**

```
define([ 'backbone', 'underscore', 'marionette', 'templates/template.mainmenu'], function (Backbone, _, Marionette, template) {
    "use strict";
    var CategoryView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({

        tagName: 'div',

        template: template['category.layout'],

        id: 'category-layout',

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('Category Layout: initialized');
        },
        onRender: function(){
            console.log(this.model) /// < --- doesn't return anything 
        },
        onShow: function(){
            console.log(this.model) ///< --- doesn't return anything 
        }
    });

    return CategoryView;
});
```

it only works when I create a LayoutView on top of the CollectionView and handle the fetching and assigning the collection from there.

```
define([ 'backbone', 'underscore', 'marionette', 
            'templates/template.mainmenu', 
            'collections/MainMenu/MM.collection.categories',
            'layouts/MainMenu/collectionview.categories'    ],
    function (Backbone, _, Marionette, template, c_Categories, cv_Categories) {
    "use strict";
    var CategoryLayoutView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({


        template: template['categories.layout'],

        regions: {
            categories : '#categories'
        },

        id: 'categories-layout',

        initialize: function(options){
            this.collection = new c_Categories();
            console.log('Category Layout: initialized');
        },

        onRender: function(){
            var categories = this.categories
            var collection = this.collection;
            collection.fetch().done(function(cData){
                categories.show(new cv_Categories({collection : collection}))
            })
        },

        onShow: function(){
        }
    });

    return CategoryLayoutView;
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you try to do this.collection = new c_Categories() in the initialize method of the CollectionView? Because it looks ok otherwise. BTW, tagName: 'div' is redundant, it's the default.

Comment: tried that too, but the result was the same :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prelimnaries**: The primary purpose of Collection/CompositeView is to properly render a Backbone.Collection, i.e. pass the collection models to the CollectionView children, and render those children. There is not involvement on your part necessary other than providing a Collection/CompositeView with―and this is key—a *pre*-filled collection.

Now, the problem you're having is that you're doing an asynchronous fetch (by default all AJAX calls are async) on your `CategoriesCollection.initialize()`. Since that initialize is being called when you define the `CategoriesCollectionView` (see its `collection` property) the fetch is likely not coming back in time when you render it. So, the CollectionView renders, but finds no models and just renders an `emptyView` if one has been provided.

**You have two options**: To do what you're doing in your LayoutView (that's not only what  I always do in my views, but I've spoken to a few of the top Marionette contributors and they do the same), or fetch synchronously (which I don't recommend for perf reasons).

**A few pointers**

1. Remove the fetch from `CategoriesCollection.initialize()` (If you want to keep it there you'll have to pass the option `{ async: false }` in the fetch, to guarantee the data will be back by the time you render your view. However, I don't recommend doing this since you'll be blocking the CPU while you're waiting for the fetch).
2. Remove the `CategoriesCollectionView.collection` property from within the `CategoriesCollectionView` definition. Instead we'll pass the collection in from withing the parent LayoutView
3. I suggest you use `.then()` rather than `.done()` for your Promise handler. Two reasons:

   a. `.then()` handles errors better: It will display a stack trace if errors go unmanaged, and the second parameter can always be used to actually handle errors that result from the Promise. 
   b. `.then()` allows you to continue chaining. Maybe not in this call, but in some other Promise you may want to invoke a series of callbacks after the call comes in. Like the name implies `.done()` is the end of the callback chain

Other than that, your solution is Best Practice.

Comment: thanks for your input. Still I need the collection to be loaded asynchronously , so I will stick to the solution that I have come up with so far.

Comment: I totally concur. Your solution follows best practices

Comment: However, you should consider points 1 and 2. You'll realize that your doing unnecessary work.

Comment: yeah I did correct that one as you suggested. Regarding the 1 point , doesn't this pareameter make the fetch synchronously ? Isn't that what will cause perf issues later on?

Comment: That point is unclear in the context of the other two. I don't want to encourage the practice of fetching synchronously.  I'll rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Example for Marionette.CollectionView - [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/shahsank3t/6Lm9ps2e/)

```
//Collection View
var CollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
    template: "#coll-template",
    childView: MainView,
    itemViewContainer: "#items"
});

//Item View    
var MainView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: "#sample-template",
    templateHelpers: function() {
        return {
            id: this.model.id
        };
    },
    onDomRefresh: function() {
        console.log("DOM REFRESH OF ITEM");
    }
});

//Creating some models
var model = new Backbone.Model({
    contentPlacement: "here",
    id: 1
});
var model2 = new Backbone.Model({
    contentPlacement: "here",
    id: 2
});
var model3 = new Backbone.Model({
    contentPlacement: "here",
    id: 3
});

//Create collection and resetting it with created models
var collection = new Backbone.Collection();
collection.reset([model, model2, model3]);


var view = new CollectionView({
    collection: collection
});
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the example , though I'd like to see one where instead of using pre-defined data you fetch all the required data from a JSON file or any other source..

Comment: I have updated my fiddle as per your required changes, hope this does the trick for you. [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/shahsank3t/6Lm9ps2e/1/)

Comment: so once I call the this.collection.fetch() , then in the "success" option I can just add  this.collection.reset( this.collection ) right?

Comment: btw , is it possible to define the backbone.collection inside the collectionview?

Comment: In your case, you can simply write, this.collection.reset(); in your success option.
No need to pass anything to reset method unless you want to reset that collection with array of models manually.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to define collection in collectionView itself. Dont pass collection to view, and instead in your collectionView, inside initialize option, you can define collection as, `this.collection = new Backbone.Collection();` and it works as expected.

Comment: well it's still not working for me , it doesn't print out the required data. Shouldn't I listen to the reset event and re-render the view once it's triggered?

Comment: Yes, you might need to re-render your collection view once you get the success callback from your fetch method. You can either add a listener to collection's reset event or can call render() directly from within success callback.

Comment: it only works when I'm passing a collection with pre-defined models , or when I fetched all the data before initializing the CollectionView and passing the collection as an argument while creating a new instance of my ColectionView...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80873/discussion-between-alexus-and-shahsank3t).

Answer (score -1):

> You need to pass childViewOptions from your collection view.

Example:

```
define([ 'backbone', 'underscore', 'marionette', 
    'collections/MainMenu/collection.categories' , 
    'layouts/MainMenu/itemview.category'], 
    function (Backbone, _, Marionette, c_Categories, iv_Category) {
    "use strict";
    var CategoriesCollectionView = Marionette.CollectionView.extend({

        tagName: 'div',

        template: null,

        id: 'categories',

        childView: iv_Category,

        collection : new c_Categories(),

        childViewOptions : function(){
            return{
                collection: this.collection
            }
        },

        initialize: function(){
            console.log('Categories Collection: initialized');

            /// or should I call fetch() from within the CV? 
            /// but how do I then pass all the data to ChildView? 
            this.collection.fetch().done(function(){

            })
        },
        onRender: function(){
            console.log(this.collection) ///<-- shows all the JSON data properly
        },
        onShow: function(){
        }
    });

    return CategoriesCollectionView;
});
```

And in your item view, you can get every model of collection passed from collection view in initialize method.

---

Example of initialize method in item view:

```
initialize: function(options){
            console.log('Category Layout: initialized');
            console.log(options.model);
        },
```

Comment: but shouldn't be the childViews be populated with the collection data automatically?

Comment: It will be populated automatically, but itemView should know which collection to use, so we pass it in childViewOptions, and as many models would be present in that collection, that many childViews would be populated automatically.

Comment: childViewOptions is used to pass data from collectionView to itemView but is not compulsorily required to pass collection through it.

Comment: even though it's working, it seems a little bit hacky...I'm certain there is a better way to.do it..